# Windows Server RDRemoteApp with Custom Configuration Argument

Tags: windows, windows-server, remoteapp

I have multiple users using a Windows Server 2016 Remotely.

Currently, each user has an `exe` file on their desktop - `program.exe` with a custom configuration argument:

```
program.exe --conf=D:/username/config.ini
```

Now I'd like to set up this `program` as a `RemoteApp` over `RDP`. How do I set the custom argument for every user individually to go to a specific path? (or a rule, like `~/config.ini` under home directory)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really clear what you are asking, however you can set the arguments for the remoteapp by right clicking, choosing "properties" and setting the command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for powershell:

New-RDRemoteApp -CollectionName "Remoteapp Collection" -DisplayName "Some program" -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Program\program.exe" -CommandLineSetting Require -RequiredCommandLine "--conf=D:/username/config.ini"